# Seven Segment Display with Verilog

Tags: verilog

everyone!

I'm working on my final project here and I find myself getting lost. essentially what I am trying to do is use my Basys board as an 8 bit signed number converter. So there are the eight switches which I pull as inputs to make a signed number such as 10111110. I then want to take that number and convert it to it's equivalent decimal value through 2's compliment. I then want to display the number on my seven-segment displays. I would love any tips or suggestions on how to start because I just can't figure out how I take the number and display it across the displays. I'll post my code and look forward to reading any suggestions you guys have for me. Thanks for the help!

```
input load, cup, cdown, rst;
input Sw7, Sw6, Sw5, Sw4, Sw3, Sw2, Sw1, Sw0;
output MyNumber[7];

seg7 h1(w, x, y, z, a, b, c, d, e,f,g);
clockdivider h2(clk0, ClkOut);


initial begin
MyNumber <= 8'b0000000;

end

always @(MyNumber)
w <= MyNumber[7]
MyNumber[6]
MyNumber[5]
MyNumber[4]
MyNumber[3]
MyNumber[2]
MyNumber[1]
MyNumber[0]
end

always @(posedge clk) begin

if(rst) begin
    MyNumber <=0;

end else if (cup) begin
    MyNumber = MyNumber + 1;

end else if (cdown) begin
    MyNumber = MyNumber - 1;

end else if (load) begin
    MyNumber[7] <= Sw0;
    MyNumber[6] <= Sw1;
    MyNumber[5] <= Sw2;
    MyNumber[4] <= Sw3;
    MyNumber[3] <= Sw4;
    MyNumber[2] <= Sw5;
    MyNumber[1] <= Sw6;
    MyNumber[0] <= Sw7;

end


end
```

And here is my seven segment display code

```
input w, x, y, z;
output reg a, b, c, d, e,f,g;
reg [6:0] a_to_g;
reg [3:0] w_to_z;

initial begin
w_to_z[3] = w;
w_to_z[2] = x;
w_to_z[1] = y;
w_to_z[0] = z;
a=0;b=0;c=0;d=0;e=0;f=0;g=0;
end 

always @(*) begin
    w_to_z[3] = w;
w_to_z[2] = x;
w_to_z[1] = y;
w_to_z[0] = z;
case(w_to_z)
    0:a_to_g=7'b0000001;
    1:a_to_g=7'b1001111;
    2:a_to_g=7'b0010010;
    3:a_to_g=7'b0000110;
   4:a_to_g=7'b1001100;
    5:a_to_g=7'b0100100;
    6:a_to_g=7'b0100000;
    7:a_to_g=7'b0001111;
    8:a_to_g=7'b0000000;
    9:a_to_g=7'b0000100;
    'ha:a_to_g=7'b0001000;
    'hb:a_to_g=7'b1100000;
    'hc:a_to_g=7'b0110001;
    'hd:a_to_g=7'b1000010;
    'hf:a_to_g=7'b0111000;
    default a_to_g=7'b1111111;
endcase
a = a_to_g[6];
b = a_to_g[5];
c = a_to_g[4];
d = a_to_g[3];
e = a_to_g[2];
f = a_to_g[1];
g = a_to_g[0];
end
```

And I totally don't want to come off like I'm looking for someone to do my assignment for me. I'm just lost and could use a push in the right direction, thanks everyone.

Comment: There are a few related questions, try searching using 'BCD'. [hexadecimal-to-bcd-conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14293216/97073) & [binary-coded-decimals-in-verilog](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14323107/97073).

Comment: I does look like you want us to write your code. Have you simulated this code? What do you mean when you say you are lost? Can you ask a specific question?

Comment: @JoeHass  
So say I have my eight digit binary number, and my four seven segment displays. Display one will be used only for a negative sign, and then display two will be either a one or display nothing. Once I've got my number loaded from the switches, I'm not entirely sure how I can take that input and put it on the last two displays. Like, if I have 0100011 how do I get display three to show a nine and display four to show another nine since that number would be 99?

Comment: You say you are "not entirely sure", so tell us what you have in mind, what you think might work, what you _are_ sure about.

Comment: @JoeHass So I'm sure that I can check the value of my first switch, and if it equals a one I can then make display one be a negative sign, and I'm also certain that if the number is less than one hundred I can leave display two off. What I"m not certain of is how I can then take that remaining number, whatever it may be and display it on the last two displays.

Comment: The [Basys 3 Reference Sheet](https://reference.digilentinc.com/basys3/refmanual#basic_io) has a very good explanation of how to use the seven segment display.